# Streamcontroller not printing previous object in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am adding an object to stream controller but during printing it is showing only the last object I added. Not the previous ones. Those are getting lost. When I add a new object, the new object is only getting shown and previous ones are getting lost.For evample i am adding`{"hello":"hi", }`3 times but it is showing that i added only 1 times.  Can you check if my code is wrong?
This is mainly a chat application so whenever someone sends message it will get added to stream controller.
This is the stream controller

```
final socketResponse= StreamController();


 Stream get getResponse =>socketResponse.stream;


@override


void dispose() {
socketResponse.close();
super.dispose();}
```

I added the the data using
`RaisedButton(onPressed: (){           print("clicked"); socketResponse.add({"hello":"hi",}) ; },child: Text("click me"),),`

**Listened the data using the following code**

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: getResponse ,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
```

`

```
    if(!snapshot.hasData){
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
      return ListView.builder
        (
          itemCount:snapshot.data.length,
          itemBuilder:(BuildContext context, index){
            print(snapshot.data);
            return ListTile(
              title:Text(snapshot.data['hello']),
            );
          });
    },

  ), `
```

**when i am clicking the button 5 times {"hello":"hi",
} would be added 5 times but when i print the value of stream only 1 {"hello":"hi",}
is printed where as this object was supposed to be shown like {"hello":"hi",},{"hello":"hi",},{"hello":"hi",},{"hello":"hi",},{"hello":"hi",} this**
**Suggest me how i can fix the problem**

Answer (score 1):

I don't really sure about how to used the streamController, so I only give the approach from the logic which I usually used in RxDart

```
socketResponse.add({"hello":"hi",}) ; }
```

this used for adding your value into your sink, so it's replace not adding value inside your StreamController, if you want to add into your sink, you need to get the value from your previous sink and add into your new sink

for example:

```
final Map<String,dynamic> value = socketResponse.value;
final Map<String,dynamic> tempMap = <String,dynamic>[];
tempMap.addAll(value);
socketResponse.add(value);
```